# Random jQuery Ajax calls inconsistently fail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using jQuery, I take form submissions and run them as AJAX requests instead. Generally, this has worked extremely well and been a robust solution. But one of my clients seems to be having certain longer forms fail inconsistently.

I was able to remotely connect to their computer and recreate the issue. Google Chrome shows the connection as "(failed)" after several seconds:

[image: Chrome web inspector showing failed request]

Tracking down the IP address in the Apache log, I seem to see an error 408:

```
x.x.x.x - - [05/Dec/2013:12:53:00 -0800] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
```

The form data is substantial, but not huge (~90 fields, nothing super long).

Additionally, other users at other locations do not seem to have the same issue. I tried disabling firewalls and Kaspersky products that the client used, but the problem still occurred.

Yet, it is inconsistent. So retrying a few times usually causes the request to succeed.

Any ideas what might cause certain queries to run into this issue? This has me stumped.

**(Update) Extra detail:**

- The requests are SSL requests.
- The server runs Apache 2.4, with no unusual timeout configurations (timeout is set to 45 seconds). Since the request fails after about 20 seconds, I do not think this is the limiting factor.

**Further update:**

- It turns out the 408 errors are completely unrelated. They are just a result of Chrome's prefetching. It seems like the actual post data never makes it to the server, since there is no access log or error log entry corresponding with it.

Comment: Sure you may have seen this, there's this mod for apache which allows you to elastically configure timeout settings.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

Answer (score 1):

If is a 408 error, it means a timeout was reached. 
1. Have you tried with a different browser?
2. Try finding the timeout settings for the server and increase it and see if that resolves the issue.
3. Use the debugger (if you can) to step through the code and see what happens with the error on the client-side

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. It did occur on all major browsers running on the same computer, so I don't think it is brewer specific. And walking through the JavaScript execution showed nothing unusual. But I should try to adjust the timeout settings, but it is odd that it takes 20 seconds in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, 20 secs seems way too long :/. So it makes the call and 20 seconds later, it times out? I'm guessing it is something on the server-side then. Does the server log the cause of the error/call stack by any chance?

Comment: The only really sign I see of the requests is the 408 error in the access log that seems to correspond with the failed requests... I don't think PHP even starts processing it, so sounds like it might be something in Apache.

Comment: Any luck on the issue? Maybe the server is blocking the request because of length

Comment: I just realized that the 408 errors were unrelated. It seems like the requests are never making it to the server, which only makes it more confusing. I am guessing it is some sort of firewall or something like that in between, but I am stumped because of the inconsistencies.

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird but it narrows things down some more. Here's what I suggest:
1. Try running the client from the same machine as the server and hit localhost if you can. If that fails reliably, then maybe there's something wrong with how the request is being made.
2. Reduce the size of the request being sent
3. Spin up a new server and make your POST request to a different endpoint (using the same code as before, just change the destination url). That can help out see whether the problem is from the request or not

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I am trying some of your suggestions and will follow-up with what I find. I appreciate the help!